# How to instantiate a object with a variable key-value pair in Javascript?

Tags: object, hashmap, template-strings

I want to instantiate a object with its key being a variable. Something along the lines of this:

```
var deleteDuplicates = function(head) {
    let dict = {
        `${head.val}`: 1
    }
}
```

Is something like this possible besides having another line write to it:

```
let dict = {}
if (head) dict[head.val] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for throwing a variable in as a key is:

```
let dict = {
   [head.val]: 1
}
```

Source: [ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)